# ImageMosaic granule sorting by resolution in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, web-mapping

I'm having trouble ensuring that the highest resolution raster is always rendered first in my ImageMosaic.

In the folder `.../svfc` I have a series of overlapping geoTiff elevation rasters at different resolutions. Each raster contains only patches of data (i.e. is ~50% NoData values), though their overall bounding boxes overlap considerably.

First, I create an external imageMosaic via restAPI using:

```
-v -u 'admin:geoserver' -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///srv/mal_data/external_data/processed_lidar/svfc" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mal/coveragestores/svfc/external.imagemosaic"
```

This creates the datastore and layer in GeoServer as expected, and creates the `svfc.shp` and `svfc.properties` files within `.../svfc`

Next, I create an `indexer.properties` file within `.../svfc` containing the following:

```
PropertyCollectors=ResolutionExtractorSPI(resolution)
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,resolution:String
Caching=false
AbsolutePath=false
```

Finally, I manually set the `Granule Sorting (WFS like syntax)` field on the `svfc` layer configuration page in GeoServer to: `resolution A`

When I examine the layer in QGIS via WMS the highest resolution granules are not rendered first (i.e. 2m res granules are covering 1m res granules). At the bottom of the image below you can see the smaller pixels of the 1m res granule peeping out from beneath the 2m res granule.

[image]

Mosaic index file

[image: Mosaic index file]

Contents of directory `/srv/mal_data/external_data/processed_lidar/svfc`:

```
indexer.properties
oxfordshire_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-2m_svfc.tif
oxfordshire_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-2m_svfc.tif.aux.xml
oxfordshire_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-50cm_svfc.tif
oxfordshire_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-50cm_svfc.tif.aux.xml
oxfordshire_merged-products_dtm-1m_svfc.tif
oxfordshire_merged-products_dtm-1m_svfc.tif.aux.xml
sample_image.dat
svfc.dbf
svfc.fix
svfc.prj
svfc.properties
svfc.qix
svfc.shp
svfc.shx
wberks_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-2m_svfc_20200602_032452.tif.aux.xml
wberks_merged-products_dtm-1m_svfc.tif.aux.xml
wsussex_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-2m_svfc.tif
wsussex_lidar-composite-dtm_dtm-2m_svfc.tif.aux.xml
wsussex_merged-products_dtm-1m_svfc.tif
wsussex_merged-products_dtm-1m_svfc.tif.aux.xml
```

Comment: We need to see how you set up the mosaic, not the GeoServer settings. What does the index look like? Please add a screenshot to show what is happening

Comment: hi, apols i've just re-read the documentation and see that I must add a field on the index file to allow sorting by that field. I previously thought the resolution would already be known to GeoServer .. So I would add a float field named 'resolution' to allow render sorting by those values?

Comment: still unable to get it working, see edits above.

Comment: does https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/tutorial.html#multi-resolution-imagery-with-reprojection help?

Comment: That's what I have been following but no joy. I'm not sure if the indexer.properties file is even being accessed? (if I insert jibberish code into it then no error is thrown).

Comment: To start with I would stop using REST for now and concentrate on getting it working in the GUI.

Comment: managed to get it to work! seems I had to recreate the imageMosaic *after* I'd created the indexer.properties file in the target directory. Now I need to find out how to set the Granule Sorting (WFS like syntax) field via restAPI...

Comment: Don't forget to write up how you did it as an answer for the benefit of others

Comment: I will but want to make sure that this behaviour / work flow is what you would expect

Comment: Sorry, yes its what i'd expect - the indexer is only used when new granules are added or the mosaic is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The indexer.properties file must be created *before* the imageMosaic extension is called.**

I completed the process using R and include the script below. Per folder, this script:

1. Deletes any pre-existing mosaic index files (caution, will delete *all* files not ending in tif)
2. Adds an indexer.properties file to enable sorting by resolution
3. Adds an external image mosaic (workspace name 'mal' in this example)
4. Edits the layer coverage.xml file to enable sorting by resolution (GeoServer installed at /usr/share/ in this example)

```
require(stringr)
require(xml2)
# create / update mosaics in GeoServer

# procDirs <- c('.../folder/of/geotiffs1','.../folder/of/geotiffs2')

  lapply(procDirs, function(x) {
    # delete pre-existing mosaic index files
    f <- list.files(x,full.names = T)
    fRm <- f[!str_detect(f,'tif')]
    lapply(fRm,function(x) try(system(paste0('rm ', x))))
    # add index properties file
    inProp <- c('PropertyCollectors=ResolutionExtractorSPI(resolution)',
                'Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,resolution:String',
                'Caching=false',
                'AbsolutePath=false')
    write.table(inProp,
                file=paste0(x,'/indexer.properties'),
                quote = F,
                row.names=F,col.names = F)
    # add new mosaic
    system2("curl",
            paste0('-v -u ',
                   shQuote('admin:geoserver'),
                   ' -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" ',
                   '-d ',paste0('"file://',x,'"'),' ',
                   '"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mal/coveragestores/',
                   basename(x),'/external.imagemosaic"'))
    
    # edit coverage file to set resolution sorting
    covLoc <- paste0('/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/mal/',basename(x),
                     '/',basename(x),'/coverage.xml')
    cov <- read_xml(covLoc)
    covString <- xml_find_all(cov, '//string')
    xml_text(covString[46]) <- 'resolution A'
    file.remove(covLoc)
    write_xml(cov,covLoc)
  })
  
  # restart geoserver for granule sorting to register
  system("sudo -kS service geoserver stop", input = '[yoursudopassword]')
  system("sudo -kS service geoserver start", input = '[yoursudopassword]')
```